# Local behavior of a Fourier series and a intgral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-series

So I have to calculate an integral that involves a Fourier series of some function. I would like to get some kind of local control of the function near zero the series is

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}\cos (x 2^n)$$

I see that I can't do a Taylor expansion of the $\cos's$ and interchange sums.
Does anyone have any idea what the local behavior of the function is like?

The integral that I want to find out if it is finite or not is

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1-f(x)}dx$$